# Create Web API in .net Core to process the Large no of records Parallel

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am developing API for to process around 25000 records. For  each record I have to call another API which will return additional details for each product .These  details needs to be updated in my database

The problem is since , I am processing large no of records & different API is being  called inside my API, processing time is very High & data may be processed incorrectly .

```
[Route("GetSymbolDetailsParallel/{Exchange?}/{MarketGuid?}/{Symbol?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSymbolDetailsParallel(string Exchange = "", string MarketGuid = "", string Symbol = "")
{
   GlobalFunctions objGolobal = new GlobalFunctions();
   MongoClient client = new MongoClient(_ConFigSettings.MongoConnectionString);
   var db = client.GetDatabase(_ConFigSettings.DatabaseName);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Symbol) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Exchange))
   {
        SymbolsBE objSymbols = db.GetCollection<SymbolsBE>("Symbols").Find(x => x.Symbol == Symbol + '.' + Exchange).FirstOrDefault();
        await objGolobal.getSymbolsDetails(objSymbols, _ConFigSettings);
   }
   else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MarketGuid))
   {
      try
      {
         // Get the List from the MongoDb Database & Pass the list to the  function
          List<SymbolsBE> lstSymbols = db.GetCollection<SymbolsBE>("Symbols").Find(x => x.MarketGuid == MarketGuid 
                                                 && x.isActive == true
                                                 && (x.Fundamental == null || x.Fundamental.Code == "")).ToList();

           GetMultipleFundamentalAsync(lstSymbols, _ConFigSettings);

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }
    }      
    return Ok("Sucess"); 
}


public async Task GetMultipleFundamentalAsync(List<SymbolsBE> lst, ConfigSettings _ConFigSettings)
{
  DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now;
  int cnt = lst.Count;
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
  {
     await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
     {

                    await getSymbolsDetails(lst[i], _ConFigSettings);
      });
   }

}
public async Task getSymbolsDetails(SymbolsBE objSymbol, ConfigSettings _ConFigSettings)
{
   // Code Download Details from API using HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync(URL)
   // This response will be saved in the Database

}
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? and what do you mean *data may be processed incorrectly*?

Comment: getSymbolsDetails() method is marked as async. Also GetAPIResponse is with keyword await.

Comment: Yeah well,the code does not make sense. You do stuff but don't return it. You use `async void` methods (which should be `async Task` methods) and you swallow exceptions. It is hard to tell what you want with this question. As it is now it is just piece of code telling us nothing.

Comment: After i got the from GetAPIResponse() , the same needs to be updated in the database. 
There are round about  10000 rows which needs to be updated through API . 
It means GetAPIResponse will be called 10000 times. GetAPIResponse takes approx 2 sec for each request. 
This is very time consuming and because of async and await the data may be updated incorrectly  

Basically , I want this process needs to be executed in the background or parallel .

Comment: Can anybody check the code , advise if the better solution is available